# how can i get key by value?

Tags: javascript, json

how can i get key by value?

this is my code.

```js
function getkey(obj, key) {
  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i] === key) {
      return obj[i];
    }
  }
}
var json = {
  test: {
    "key1": {
      "inkey1": "value1",
      "inkey2": "value2"
    },
    "key2": {
      "inkey3": "value3",
      "inkey4": "value4"
    }
  }
}
console.log(getkey(json, "value2"));
```

i want get key1 by value2
how can i get key1?

please help me!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I mean what you want as the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non nested version

```
function getKeyByValue(obj, value) {
  for (let key in obj) {
     for (let inkey in obj[key]) {
       if (obj[key][inkey] === value) {
         return key;
       }
     }
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(json['test'], "value2")); //key1
```

For nested version which you don't know how deep your object is

```
function getKeyByValue(obj, value, path) {
  path = path ? path + '.' : '';
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (obj[key] === value) {
        return path + key;
      } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        let found = getKeyByValue(obj[key], value, path + key);
        if (found) {
            return found;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(json, "value2")); //"test.key1.inkey2"
```

Comment: @DaemonWarrior If you specify console.log(getKeyByValue(json['test'], "value2")); it will return key1

Comment: can i get also value1 by key1?

Comment: @DaemonWarrior yes you can

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, one way is to use a variation on your function and to apply recursion. See code snippet below:

```js
function getkey(obj, key) {
  for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
    if (Object.values(obj)[i] === key) {
      return Object.keys(obj)[i];
    }
    if (Object.values(obj)[i].constructor == Object) {
      return getkey(Object.values(obj)[i], key)
    }
  }
}
var json = {
  test: {
    "key1": {
      "inkey1": "value1",
      "inkey2": "value2"
    },
    "key2": {
      "inkey3": "value3",
      "inkey4": "value4"
    }
  }
}
console.log(getkey(json, "value2"));
```

Results in `inkey2`. This should work no matter how deeply nested the key is in your object.